# Consecutive number for specific value in the field

Tags: sql-server, count

I'm using SQL Server 2017.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [T1] 
(
    REC_ID decimal(28,6) NOT NULL,
    BUSINESS_NR decimal(10,6) NULL,
    Description varchar(20) NULL,
);

INSERT INTO T1 (REC_ID,BUSINESS_NR, Description)
VALUES (312, 1, 'Created'),
       (314, 1, 'Adjustment'),
       (356, 2, 'Created'),
       (388, 1, 'NoChange'),
       (565, 2, 'Adjustment'),
       (701, 2, 'NoChange'),
       (769, 1, 'Adjustment'),
       (832, 2, 'Adjustment'),
       (992, 2, 'Closed'),
       (995, 1, 'Closed');
```

Question:

I would like to give each 'Adjustment' a consecutive number per Business_NR.

Example

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1 ....... 
ORDER BY Business_NR ASC, REC_ID ASC
```

Output:

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
| REC_ID | BUSINESS_NR | Description | Adjustment Count|
+--------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
|    312 |           1 | Created     |                 |
|    314 |           1 | Adjustment  |        1        |
|    388 |           1 | NoChange    |                 |
|    769 |           1 | Adjustment  |        2        |
|    995 |           1 | Closed      |                 |
|    356 |           2 | Created     |                 |
|    565 |           2 | Adjustment  |        1        |
|    701 |           2 | NoChange    |                 |
|    832 |           2 | Adjustment  |        2        |
|    992 |           2 | Closed      |                 |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Info: the `REC_ID` is unique and consecutive for each table entry.

I have no useful attempt to show and therefore have not added any query samples.

SQL FIDDLE: [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ee6a29/4)

Comment: _I would like to give each 'Adjustment' a consecutive number per Business ID_ - there are no `BuisnessId`, Did you mean `Business_NR`? Did you check [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you just want a `ROW_NUMBER` in a `CASE` expression:

```sql
CASE [Description] WHEN 'Adjustment' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BUSINESS_NR, [Description] ORDER BY REC_ID ASC) END AS AdjustmentCount
```